# Redesign Token control in the Multicombobox ui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have this request: I want to replace sap system cancel icon by decline one for a token displayed in multicombobox.

[image]

For my custom Token control (under Multicombobox), I could successfully make it, by this code.

```
sap.ui.define([
  'sap/m/Token',
], function (Token) {
  'use strict';

  return Token.extend('drex.control.customToken', {
    metadata: {},

    init: function () {
      Token.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
      // setting to decline icon, as a default is system-cancel
      const deleteIcon = this.getAggregation("deleteIcon");
      deleteIcon.setProperty('src', 'sap-icon://decline');
    },

    _tokenIconPress: function(oEvent) {
      // fire "delete" event before Tokenizer's _onTokenDelete because the Tokenizer will destroy the token
      // and the token's delete handler will not be executed
      this.fireDelete({
        token : this
      });

      oEvent.preventDefault();
    },

    renderer: 'sap.m.TokenRenderer'
  })
});
```

xml

```
<MultiComboBox
    items="{
        path: 'diseaseList>/allDiseases'
    }"
    selectionChange="onSelectionDiseaseChange"
    selectedKeys="{filterModel>/disease}"
    <core:Item key="{diseaseList>meshId}" text="{diseaseList>meshName}"/>
</MultiComboBox>
<HBox wrap="Wrap" items="{diseaseList>/selectedDiseasesAsTokens}">
    <items>
        <drex:customToken key="{diseaseList>meshId}"
                          class="sidebarToken"
                          text="{diseaseList>meshName}"
                          delete="onDeleteDiseaseToken"/>
    </items>
</HBox>
```

Unfortunately, I don't see a way that I can control token appearance in the Multicombobox. Is there any way, I can provide my token instead of `<core:Item key="{diseaseList>meshId}" text="{diseaseList>meshName}"/>` ?

Comment: Do you need to show the Tokens in your HBox AND in your MultiComboBox? Why?

Comment: Easy answer is: when there are more than 3 Tokens in combobox they are not displayed , but rather hidden behind "# Items" phrase @Marc